# find all applied coupon code/rules for an order

Tags: orders, coupon

Is it possible to find out all coupon codes was applied for an specific order?

i can only found out 1 coupon codes was applied for an order in sales_flat_order table. In the table, only 1 field was storing a coupon code (last code applied).

anyone know how to do that?

Comment: In default magento functionality is applied only one coupon code in order at time.
Have you add any custom code to apply multiple coupon code to order?

Comment: no, but if i apply a rule which is "Stop Further Rules Processing = false", so i can apply two rule one by one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php
$order_id = 101;
$items = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()
    ->addFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$order_id));

foreach($items as $item){
    if($item->getAppliedRuleIds() == '') {
        continue;
    }
    foreach(explode(",",$item->getAppliedRuleIds()) as $ruleId){       
         //Load the rule object
        $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($ruleId); //Shopping Cart Rules //$rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load($ruleId); catalog rules
        // Throw out some information like the rule name what product it was applied to
        echo "<p> Applied Rule Name: ".$rule->getName()." & Code : ".$rule->getCouponCode()."</p>";
        echo "\t";
    }
}

?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php
$order_id = 11060;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);

foreach(explode(",",$order->getAppliedRuleIds()) as $ruleId){       
 //Load the rule object
 $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($ruleId); //Shopping Cart Rules //$rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load($ruleId); catalog rules
 // Throw out some information like the rule name what product it was applied to
 echo "<p> Applied Rule Name: ".$rule->getName()." & Code : ".$rule->getCouponCode()."</p>";
 echo "\t";
}    

?>
```

Comment: This might work and might not work. If someone placed an order last week using a coupon code and in the mean time you change the coupon code or deleted the discount rule you won't get the coupon code value.

Comment: i have tried, the name and code didn't print out

Comment: updated ans pls check now

Comment: both solution i have tried for an order which has applied two rules (one free shipping, one discount off), but only print out discount off rule. I the customer apply the rules one by one, seems there is no way to find out

Comment: If your print_r($order->getAppliedRuleIds()); then how may ids found?

Comment: can you please check this your end for the particular order ?

Comment: i checked the db, only 1 ids, but actually 2 rules were applied. The shipping cart rules applied but not recorded.

Answer (score 5):

You find only one code, because you can only have one code applied to the order.
You can have multiple discount rules but only one of them can have a code.

You can get the coupon code applied like this:

```
$order->getCouponCode();
```

where `$order` is an instance of the order model.

and you can get the ids of all the rules that are applied to the order, like this:

```
$order->getAppliedRuleIds();
```

Comment: there are no ways to  find out which rules were applied?

Comment: based on the rule ids, you can retrieve the rules from the database but that's not always going to work if you delete the rules or change them over time.